# nextjs user management login

Tags: typescript, authentication, next.js, supabase

When I'm signing in for nextjs usermanagement supabase, the button just changing the signin and nothing happen but if I refresh the page it will go to /account, my env file is working also

(https://github.com/supabase/supabase/tree/master/examples/user-management/nextjs-user-management)

```
app/auth/callback/route.ts

import { createRouteHandlerClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  const supabase = createRouteHandlerClient({ cookies })
  const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url)
  const code = searchParams.get('code')

  if (code) {
    await supabase.auth.exchangeCodeForSession(code)
  }

  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/account', req.url), {
    status: 200
  })
}
```

here is my middleware.ts

```
import { createMiddlewareClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const res = NextResponse.next()
  const supabase = createMiddlewareClient({ req, res })

  const {
    data: { user },
  } = await supabase.auth.getUser()

  // if user is signed in and the current path is / redirect the user to /account
  if (user && req.nextUrl.pathname === '/') {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/account', req.url))
  }

  // if user is not signed in and the current path is not / redirect the user to /
  if (!user && req.nextUrl.pathname !== '/') {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', req.url))
  }

  return res
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/', '/account'],
}
```

I remove

> view="magic_link"
> Cause I only need the login

auth-form.tsx

```
'use client'
import { Auth } from '@supabase/auth-ui-react'
import { ThemeSupa } from '@supabase/auth-ui-shared'
import { createClientComponentClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'
import { Database } from './database.types'

export default function AuthForm() {
  const supabase = createClientComponentClient<Database>()

  return (
    <Auth
      supabaseClient={supabase}
      appearance={{ theme: ThemeSupa }}
      theme="dark"
      showLinks={false}
      providers={[]}
      redirectTo="http://localhost:3000/auth/callback"
    />
  )
}
```

[image: sample image for login]

I already check this but still not working
[text](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-nextjs)

Comment: Using redirectTo on the Auth UI doesn't do anything when doing signIn with email/password. You need to handle that redirect yourself by listening to the `onAuthStateChange` for the supabase object you are passing to the Auth UI and then redirecting using the means the framework you are using provides.

Comment: We had a lot of problems with the Auth UI redirecting properly. We just ended up building our own sign in form, and added a redirect once it completed properly.